# AutoEncoder huge loss not converging

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

I am trying to use an AutoEncoder in order to reduce dimensions. However, the loss is huge and I am not sure what I did wrong. This is what the loss looks like:

Epoch 33/150
49/49 [==============================] - 0s 10ms/step - loss: 13991174768839351313119576064.0000 - val_loss: 77714384326348058472067629056.0000

Epoch 34/150
49/49 [==============================] - 1s 10ms/step - loss: 13991178310614213465353486336.0000 - val_loss: 77714384326348058472067629056.0000

I have scaled and normalised the data prior to running the AutoEncoder. The code was mostly copy and pasted from a site since I wanted to get an idea of how this works first. The input is with 5950 features and I wanted to reduce the dimensions to around 200. The input is 1 dimensional tabular data.

```
encoding_dim = 200

input_df = Input(shape=(5950,))
encoded = Dense(encoding_dim, activation='relu')(input_df)
decoded = Dense(5950, activation='sigmoid')(encoded)

autoencoder = Model(input_df, decoded)

encoder = Model(input_df, encoded)

autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error')

autoencoder.fit(df, df, epochs=150, batch_size=20, shuffle=True, validation_data=(tx, tx))
```

I am using the tensor flow keras package.

Comment: Provde sample data if possible

Comment: Is your data reducible to 200 dimension? is it in the range of (0, 1)?

Comment: Yes, I used MinMaxScaler so its between 0 and 1. Its definitely reducible. PCA works and reduces the data to 160 dimensions for 0.95 variance explained.

Comment: You need to double check your data and/or provide a complete reproducible example. With 6k dimensions and values between 0 and 1, the total error for one example cannot be larger than 6k (at most 1 per dimension), so there is definitely something off here.

Comment: Could it be that there are too many dimensions for too little samples? I tried running PCA first to reduce dimensions to 900 and the loss was fine. Theres only 1000 samples btw.